# get wikipedia parent category of category

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using wikimedia api and I need to get a parent category of category (e.g 'Mammals by common name' is parent category for category 'dogs'. But still I can't find out good solution. I was thinging abouth sth like

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=dogs&prop=categories&clcategories=Category:Mammals%20by%20common%20name
```

but dogs is category not page so the output is like if 'Mammals by common name' wasnt parent category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query checks whether [the *article* Dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dogs&redirect=no) (which is actually a redirect to Dog) belongs to Category:Mammals by common name, which it doesn't. If you want to check [the *category* Dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDogs), you need to specify that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Category:Dogs&prop=categories&clcategories=Category:Mammals%20by%20common%20name

Comment: If you want all the categories Category:Dogs is in, remove the last parameter clcategories. (Also note that Category:Mammals by common name has been deleted.)